# how can I make the django return json data human read able

Tags: json, django, api

every one, I have

> models.py

```
.......

class ProductsTbl(models.Model):
    model_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': "這 model number 已經被註冊了 ."
        }
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    feature = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    release = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    twtime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    hktime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    shtime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    jptime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    suggest = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    cataloggroup = models.ManyToManyField(CatalogGroup)
    place = models.ManyToManyField(Place)
    scale = models.ManyToManyField(Scale)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    useredit = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_imagep_Product, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''

        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()

        return super(ProductsTbl, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and ,I am working for the api return the json data,here is

> views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core import serializers
.....
def get_index(request):

    obj = ProductsTbl.objects.order_by('-created')
    data = serializers.serialize("json", obj)

    return JsonResponse(data,safe=False)
```

however, I got return the json data like this

[image]

my question is how can I make the django return json data human read able like this

[image]

thanks for any one who reply to me

Comment: You are serializing twice; once in the serializers call, and once in JsonResponse. Don't do that.

Comment: you mean I "from django.core import serializers" and "data = serializers.serialize("json", obj)"  ??

Comment: `serializers.serialize('json', obj)` converts the object to a JSON string. Then `JsonResponse` converts it to a string *again*; so the content is double-escaped.

Comment: thank you, after I change the  return JsonResponse(data,safe=False) --> return HttpResponse(data)  , it can work

Answer (score 0):

User DRF api_view

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view()
def get_index(request):

    obj = ProductsTbl.objects.order_by('-created')
    data = serializers.serialize("json", obj)

    return Response(data)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,I have pip install DRF, but I got "Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not set `.queryset` or have a `.get_queryset()` method."

Answer (score 0):

It may work for you change your views.py as follows:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core import serializers
.....
def get_index(request):

    obj = ProductsTbl.objects.order_by('-created')
    data = self.stdout.write(serializers.serialize("json",
                                        obj,
                                        indent=2))

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data),content_type="application/json")
```

Or see [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/) you will get some idea.